# Query for array values within jsonb column

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

I have a `jsonb` column called `chores` in my `work` table with data looking something like this:

`[{"task": "feed_dog", "value": "Daily"},{"task": "mop_floor", "value": "Weekly"]`

There could be zero to dozens of tasks in the `chores` array for each user.

How can I query by task name? For example, pull all records where at least one `task` is `feed_dog`.

`SELECT chores->>'task' FROM work` returns a bunch of `null` results, as does `SELECT chores->'task' FROM work`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to unnest the array:

```
select w.*
from "work" w
where exists (select *
              from jsonb_array_elements(w.chores) as t(task)
              where t.task ->> 'task" = 'feed_dog');
```

With Postgres 12 this is a bit easier to write:

```
select *
from "work" w
where jsonb_path_exists(w.chores, '$[*] ? (@.task == "feed_dog")')
```